# LinqPad Error: Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linqpad

When using linqPad I get the following error:

> Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type.

When copying in the following code.

Any idea what could be wrong. I am using the Entity Framework and have linqPad configured to read off an Entity Framework object.

Can I use linqPad to create EF queries or is it strictly linq?

```
dim db As  PlanITEntities = New PlanITEntities

Dim projects = From p In db.Projects.Include(Function(p) p.AvailableSpaceTypes) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.DisadvantageDegree) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.FundingSources) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.PartnerApprovalStatusCode) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.PhysicalConstraintTypes) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.PolicyConstraintTypes) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.Profile) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.Program) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.Program1) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.Recommendation) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.RequestType) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.SchematicDesignSource) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.Recommendation1) _
                                    .Include(Function(p) p.StatusCode) _
              Where (p.DeleteFlag <> True) _
              Select p
```

Comment: You can definitely use EF with LinqPad, but did you follow these [steps](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx) when you setup your connection for EF in LinqPad?

Comment: Also in the `Language` dropdown what do you have selected? `VB Expression`, `VB Statement(s)` or `VB Program`?

Comment: I thought include only took a string as a parameter. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes ... I have the connection properly setup with linqPad. I had the drop down selected to VB Statements

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that one or more of the properties of object "p" is not a string.  However, you most likely are misunderstanding what .Include does.  It eager-loads whichever related tables you specify.  So if you had:

```
Dim projects = From p In db.Projects.Include("Managers")
```

it would eager-load all of the related records from your "Managers" table for each row in your "Projects" table when the query is executed.  Somehow, I don't think this is what you are trying to accomplish with the code you posted.

Comment: This is someone else's code I'm trying to debug. It looks like all the items in these include statements refer to lookup tables.

Comment: And the lookup tables have the same name as whatever strings are referred to in p.Program, etc.?

Comment: It looks like all do but Program1 and recommendation1. I took those out and the same error.

Comment: Are they all tables directly related to Projects?

Comment: All tables are related.

Comment: So let me get this straight...  The "Projects" table has columns named "AvailableSpaceTypes", "DisadvantageDegree", etc. and ALL of these columns hold String (varchar or nvarchar) values, and every one of these String values is the name of a different (lookup) table?

Answer (score 0):

the signature for include that takes a lambda expression is in the system.data.entity assembly, so probably won't work with linqPad.